# Custom tableview Cell position is wrong

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

I want to implement the chat bubble for my app,everything goes fine except the positioning of those cells. I wonder if there is a way to haddle this, this is so awkward to have a screen like this
(I have only 1 section and 2 rows in this tableview)
Thx for attence the cells look like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7s3ed.jpg

The 2nd line should be in the second cell but it appers in the 3rd one and i dont know why

These are the code for my custom view for my custom class:

```
class DialogCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var iconImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var messageBackgroundView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var messageContentTextView: UITextView!
var maximumSize:CGSize = CGSize(width: 150, height: 1000)
var padding:CGFloat = 10
var exactSize:CGSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
let magicNumber:CGFloat = 50

func setViews(icon:UIImage,messageContent:String,backgroungImage:UIImage){
    iconImageView = UIImageView()
    messageContentTextView = UITextView()
    messageBackgroundView = UIImageView()
    iconImageView.layer.cornerRadius = magicNumber / 8
    iconImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    let orginX = self.frame.origin.x
    let orginY = self.frame.origin.y
    self.iconImageView.frame.origin.x = orginX + padding
    self.iconImageView.frame.origin.y = orginY + padding
    self.iconImageView.image = icon
    self.iconImageView.frame.size = CGSize(width: magicNumber, height: magicNumber)


    messageContentTextView.text = messageContent
    exactSize = messageContentTextView.sizeThatFits(maximumSize)
    self.messageContentTextView.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: orginX +  3 * padding + magicNumber, y: orginY + padding),
        size: exactSize)
    self.messageContentTextView.allowsEditingTextAttributes = false
    //        self.messageContentTextView.
    self.messageContentTextView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    //        exactSize.height
    exactSize.width += 1.5 * padding
    exactSize.height += 0.5 * padding
    var new_image = backgroungImage.resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsets(top: 15, left: 10, bottom: 5, right: 5), resizingMode: UIImageResizingMode.Tile)
    messageBackgroundView.image = new_image
    self.messageBackgroundView.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: orginX +  2 * padding + magicNumber, y: orginY + padding),
        size: exactSize)





    self.layer.opacity = 0.3
    self.addSubview(iconImageView)
    self.addSubview(messageBackgroundView)
    self.addSubview(messageContentTextView)
}
![}][2]
```

And the main method in my tableView Controller

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as DialogCell
       // dialogues[indexPath.row % dialogues.count]
        var str:String = "\(indexPath.row) Line"
        for _ in 0...2 {
            str += str
        }
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row) Line"
        cell.setViews(UIImage(named: "minion")!, messageContent: str, backgroungImage: UIImage(named: "dialogue")!)
        return cell}
```

Comment: Very sorry for no image because i'm new here and not allowed to post image.

Comment: You can use an image sharing server like http://imgur.com to upload your screen shots. It will help us, help you.

Comment: I find the bug here! The " self.frame.origin.x" is the x axis if self(DialogCell) in its parentView---which is the tableview. So this would vary every time when the cell is dequeued  from the ViewController which makes its position vary by a times of cell's height.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact answer but I can advise a different way which I did.

You can add an UIScrollView to your controller and every time when a message received add it to your scrollView dynamically and change the contentSize of scroll.Also you need to control your label positions every time. This can be another way but it's not your answer.

Comment: After a delete the line code let orginY = self.frame.origin.y,it works. Because this originY is the Y axis of the cell in the whole table view, which is extra for the view cells

Comment: I really didn't understand your question. You should be more clear. The problem is about cell?

Comment: I have fixed the bug after i delete the code of "orginY = self.frame.origin.y" Simply offers 0 as the cell's frame's origin is fine